# Angular js Dependency Injection not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I tried a very simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see i inclueded `cordova.js`, `angular.js` and a module `app.js`.
You can add angular services to modules using dependency injection, so i 
tried the following:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.run(function($document) {
    $document.on('deviceready' function() {
        alert("deviceready");
    });
});
```

Unfortunately the alert is never called. That means that the callback method for 'deviceready' is never called so the injection seems to fail.

So im asking what is wrong with the code above?

**EDIT**

whole log output when i start the app:

```
04-18 17:55:27.430: I/CordovaLog(13660): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
04-18 17:55:27.430: D/CordovaActivity(13660): CordovaActivity.init()
04-18 17:55:27.476: I/WebViewFactory(13660): Loading com.google.android.webview version 40 (1832189-arm) (code 424501)
04-18 17:55:27.510: I/LibraryLoader(13660): Time to load native libraries: 8 ms (timestamps 1958-1966)
04-18 17:55:27.511: I/LibraryLoader(13660): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
04-18 17:55:27.533: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(13660): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {3d68a6e5}
04-18 17:55:27.533: I/LibraryLoader(13660): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
04-18 17:55:27.534: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(108)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
04-18 17:55:27.542: I/BrowserStartupController(13660): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
04-18 17:55:27.547: W/art(13660): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-18 17:55:27.568: W/chromium(13660): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
04-18 17:55:27.569: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=31 off=35788 len=3738
04-18 17:55:27.570: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(76)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:32 off:390788 len:1143511
04-18 17:55:27.574: W/AudioManagerAndroid(13660): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
04-18 17:55:27.581: I/Adreno-EGL(13660): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/15/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
04-18 17:55:27.714: W/chromium(13660): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(328)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
04-18 17:55:27.748: W/art(13660): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-18 17:55:27.759: W/AwContents(13660): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
04-18 17:55:27.760: D/CordovaActivity(13660): CordovaActivity.createViews()
04-18 17:55:27.791: D/PluginManager(13660): init()
04-18 17:55:27.799: D/CordovaWebView(13660): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: LGE
04-18 17:55:27.811: W/art(13660): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-18 17:55:27.812: W/art(13660): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-18 17:55:27.812: D/CordovaWebView(13660): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
04-18 17:55:27.812: D/CordovaWebView(13660): >>> loadUrlNow()
04-18 17:55:27.831: D/CordovaActivity(13660): Resuming the App
04-18 17:55:27.840: D/OpenGLRenderer(13660): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-18 17:55:27.851: D/Atlas(13660): Validating map...
04-18 17:55:27.895: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(13660): Ignore this event
04-18 17:55:27.908: I/OpenGLRenderer(13660): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-18 17:55:27.914: D/OpenGLRenderer(13660): Enabling debug mode 0
04-18 17:55:28.094: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(13660): Ignore this event
04-18 17:55:28.131: D/CordovaWebViewClient(13660): onPageStarted(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
04-18 17:55:28.131: D/CordovaActivity(13660): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
04-18 17:55:28.160: W/BindingManager(13660): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 13660
04-18 17:55:28.192: D/CordovaLog(13660): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 7 : The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.
04-18 17:55:28.193: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (7)
04-18 17:55:28.294: D/JsMessageQueue(13660): Set native->JS mode to OnlineEventsBridgeMode
04-18 17:55:28.367: D/CordovaActivity(13660): onMessage(spinner,stop)
04-18 17:55:28.595: D/CordovaLog(13660): file:///android_asset/www/js/modules/app.js: Line 10 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
04-18 17:55:28.596: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/modules/app.js (10)
04-18 17:55:28.598: D/CordovaLog(13660): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 16 : Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
04-18 17:55:28.598: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (16)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660): file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js: Line 4138 : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660): Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:63:12
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1774:17
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at ensure (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1698:38)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at module (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1772:14)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:4115:22
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:323:20)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:4099:5)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at createInjector (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:4025:11)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at doBootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1452:20)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660):     at bootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1473:12)
04-18 17:55:28.769: D/CordovaLog(13660): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'MyApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DMyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A63%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1774%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1698%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1772%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A4115%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A323%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A4099%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A4025%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1452%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1473%3A12)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660): [INFO:CONSOLE(4138)] "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660): Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:63:12
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1774:17
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at ensure (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1698:38)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at module (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1772:14)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:4115:22
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:323:20)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:4099:5)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at createInjector (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:4025:11)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at doBootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1452:20)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660):     at bootstrap (file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js:1473:12)
04-18 17:55:28.770: I/chromium(13660): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'MyApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DMyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A63%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1774%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1698%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1772%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A4115%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A323%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A4099%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A4025%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1452%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%3A1473%3A12)", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/libs/angular.js (4138)
04-18 17:55:28.774: D/CordovaWebViewClient(13660): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
04-18 17:55:28.774: D/CordovaActivity(13660): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
04-18 17:56:03.805: D/CordovaActivity(13660): Paused the application!
04-18 17:56:03.806: D/CordovaWebView(13660): Handle the pause
```

Comment: Any javascript errors? Take a look at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html

Comment: yes i read this. this is without angular.js. i want to use angular.js and i wanted to create a module. and what i posted above should work because of dependency injection. `$document` is a service which provides a wrapper for `window.document`

Comment: That does not necessarily mean that the injection is wrong. For instance, if you do `console.log($document)` inside the run block you could easily see. (or alternatively, check for console errors)

Comment: i posted the whole logcat output above. there seems to be a problem with the 'MyApp' module. output is saying that i misspelled it but its wrong. everything should be ok with the module name.

Comment: Could you try to load the scripts at the head section instead of the body ? Or perhaps you need to wait for a DOM ready event before doing the `app.initialize()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in your app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.run(function($document) {
    // was missing comma here \/
    $document.on('deviceready', function() {
        alert("deviceready");
    });
});
```